# Protect contents of a safe with a (partial) vacuum

Tags: vacuum

UPDATE:  This was tagged as off-topic with it being more of an engineering issue.   I disagree in that I don't want to know how to pull a vacuum on a safe but instead from a physics point of view what would happen.  I've accepted the answer from @akhmeteli.

thx for the insights.

ORIGINAL Question:

With all of the horrible fires going on on the west coast of the US I've been wondering if a fire/gun safe could be made more fire proof by pulling a partial vacuum on the interior.  This would keep down the interior temperature (I assume) due to the limited amount of molecules that can be excited.

The question is how will a gun, computer hard drives and papers be effected by long term exposure to a vacuum.   I'm assuming that nothing is powered on of course.

Comment: Hi Bob, welcome to PSE. Simplest answer, dig a hole and put the (fireproof) safe there. 2 or 3 feet down should do it. Vacuum would dry out the moisture in paper relatively quickly, but I can't see the other two items being affected.

Comment: A vacuum would very possibly be harmful to the ammunition.

Comment: My grandfather told a story of a terrible fire, now nearly 100 years ago. The owner of a store had a safe. He wanted to open it immediately after finding it in the ashes. Grandpa tried to talk him out of it. The safe was still hot. The owner insisted. The contents burned as soon as the door was opened.  I can't say how true this is.

Comment: I've seen a fare few gun safes rated to a few hundred degrees simply due to materials. Not sure how hot the fire in CA are getting, but I imagine the safes would be fine.

Comment: There are fire safe boxes rated up to $1600^\circ F$, and the solution there is to put MORE insulating material in the way, instead of less!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Philip Wood mentioned, vacuum does not prevent eventual increase of the temperature of the safe contents, however, full vacuum may prevent burning of the contents due to lack of oxygen. On the other hand, filling the safe with nitrogen can serve the same purpose, and it may be advantageous to have no or little pressure differential. I don't see why nitrogen would be worse for the contents than air.

Answer (score 6):

The contents of the safe will reach the temperature of its walls, even if there is a vacuum between the contents and the walls. This will happen because electromagnetic radiation (mostly infrared) will pass between walls and contents (and vice versa). The vacuum (as opposed to air) will slow down the rate at which the temperatures equalise, as it won't support convection, but it won't *stop* the equalisation process.